# Return records where 2 columns don't match

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to find records where two columns don't match. In order to do this I need to divide one of the columns by 100 (as it is in %).

My table:

```
|artno|artno2|Quantity_Percent|Quantity_pcs|
|1111 |aaaa  |       28       |    0,28    |
|1111 |bbbb  |        0,65    |    0,017   |
```

Query:

```
Select artno, artno2, (Quantity_Percent / 100) as Percent, Quantity_pcs
From Table1
Where artno = '1111'
```

Turns this in to:

```
|artno|artno2|     Percent    |Quantity_pcs|
|1111 |aaaa  |        0,28    |    0,28    |
|1111 |bbbb  |        0,0065  |    0,017   |
```

So far so good; but if I want the query to return only the 2nd row where the  Quantity_Percent and Quantity_pcs columns don't match, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

SisU

Comment: Did you try `Select artno, artno2, (Quantity_Procent / 100) as Procent, Quantity_pcs
From Table1
Where Quantity_Procent <> Quntity_pcs`? Or if you need also to select the `artno`, then `Select artno, artno2, (Quantity_Procent / 100) as Procent, Quantity_pcs
From Table1
Where (artno = '1111') and (Quantity_Procent <> Quntity_pcs)`.

Comment: Which implementation of SQL? The operator to use may differ. Anyway, I'm sure some basic tutorial about it would explain which operator to use here.

Comment: Sure but that will return all records as Quantity_Procent need to be divided with 100 to match any field.

Comment: You mean _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: tsql, plsql, MySQL?

Comment: @jarlh, I've edited this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you need to add to your `WHERE` clause is

```
AND Quantity_Percent <> Quantity_pcs * 100
```

This condition replaces division with multiplication. In addition, you could exclude rows based on a threshold:

```
AND ABS(Quantity_Percent - Quantity_pcs * 100) > 1E-6
```

Comment: This gives the same result as Uchiha_Itachi's query (see comment). I also changed the Procent to percent.

Comment: @SisU Try the edited query. If it does not work either, try playing with `1E-6` a little - go to, say, `1E-3` or even `1E-2` and see what happens.

Comment: This 
    'AND ABS(Quantity_Percent - Quantity_pcs * 100) > 1E-6' 
worked. I wrote it "<" instead of ">" the first time. Was a bit stressed sorry. But thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Just add that condition with `and`

**For Example With your query**:

```
Select artno, artno2, (Quantity_Procent / 100) as Procent, Quantity_pcs
From Table1
Where artno = '1111' and Quantity_Procent != (Quntity_pcs*100);
```

If you want that for all `atno` then put this `Quantity_Procent != (Quntity_pcs*100)` in your `where` condition.

Comment: Its' wierd, this should work but it returns the artno2 anyway. I know that it's partly working as the result has more records than I had in this example. And most of the ones that match is not returned but some are. And the bbbb is one of those (If that makes sense?).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the condition for Quality_Percent and Quality_pcs don't match...
just add the below condition 
`SELECT * FROM ([YOUR_QUERY]) WHERE Percent!=Quality_pcs`

So that your query will be like below

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT artno, artno2, (Quantity_Percent / 100) as Percent, Quantity_pcs
FROM Table1
WHERE artno = '1111') 
WHERE  Percent != Quality_pcs`

Hope this will help you